# \LaTeX logo in tufte-book

Tags: errors, tufte, logos

`\LaTeX` will not typeset as the designed logo in tufte-book.

```
  \documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

  \begin{document}

  \title{My book} 

  \author{me} 

  \maketitle 

  \chapter{First chapter}

  This book was written in $\LaTeX$.

  \end{document}
```

How can one fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does, but you get a funny error:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
```

This is because of how `\LaTeX` is defined:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1644:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
        {\sbox\z@ T%
         \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                              \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                              \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                              A}%
                        \vss}%
        }%
        \kern-.15em%
        \TeX}
```

Now let's look at `\TeX`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1643:
\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX\@}
```

and that's where the error comes from: `\@` is used to mark the `X` like a lower case letter, as far as the space factor is concerned.

Well, you are *not* supposed to use `\LaTeX` in math mode, whatever our MathJax friends think. `;-)` The correct input is just

```
This book was written in \LaTeX.
```

---

By the way, if you want to properly typeset the LaTeX logo in MathJax, please use

```
$\mathrm{\LaTeX}$
```

[image]

Can you see the difference?

Comment: I want to mention that for many months I used to write simply `$\LaTeX$` in math, but since @egreg shows the difference I could improve my typography skills. Thanks to him and to @David for asking!!